# Send AVPacket over Network

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm generating AVPackets with an encoder with ffmpeg and now I want to send them with UDP to another Computer and show them there.
The problem is I don't know how to convert the packet to bytes and back. I tried this to copy the package:

```
AVPacket newPacket = avcodec.av_packet_alloc();


ByteBuffer byteBuffer = packet.buf().buffer().asByteBuffer();
int bufferSize = byteBuffer.capacity();
byte bytes[] = new byte[bufferSize];
byteBuffer.get(bytes);
AVBufferRef newBufferRef = avutil.av_buffer_alloc(bufferSize);
newBufferRef.data(new BytePointer(bytes));
newPacket.buf(newBufferRef);


ByteBuffer dataBuffer = packet.data().asByteBuffer();
int dataSize = dataBuffer.capacity();
byte dataBytes[] = new byte[dataSize];
dataBuffer.get(dataBytes);
BytePointer dataPointer = new BytePointer(dataBytes);
newPacket.data(dataPointer);


newPacket.dts(packet.dts());
newPacket.duration(packet.duration());
newPacket.flags(packet.flags());
newPacket.pos(packet.pos());
newPacket.pts(packet.pts());
newPacket.side_data_elems(0);
newPacket.size(packet.size());
newPacket.stream_index(packet.stream_index());


videoPlayer.sendPacket(newPacket);
```

This gives me this Error:

```
[h264 @ 0000018951be8440] Invalid NAL unit size (3290676 > 77).
[h264 @ 0000018951be8440] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 0000018951bf6480] Invalid NAL unit size (15305314 > 163).
[h264 @ 0000018951bf6480] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

The problem is `newPacket.data()`. When I set it directly: `newPacket.data(packet.data())`
it works. Also `packet.data().asByteBuffer().capacity()` returns 1 and `packet.data().capacity()` returns 0.

This is my method that creates the decoder:

```
private void startUnsafe() throws Exception
    {
        int result;

        convertContext = null;
        codec = null;
        codecContext = null;
        AVFrame = null;
        RGBAVFrame = null;
        frame = new Frame();

        codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codecID);
        if(codec == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to find decoder");
        }

        codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
        if(codecContext == null)
        {
            releaseUnsafe();
            throw new Exception("Unable to alloc codec context!");
        }

        AVCodecParameters para = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
        para.bit_rate(streamBitrate);
        para.width(streamWidth);
        para.height(streamHeight);
        para.codec_id(codecID);
        para.codec_type(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        try
        {
            byte extradataByte[] = Files.readAllBytes(new File("extradata.byte").toPath());
            para.extradata(new BytePointer(extradataByte));
            para.extradata_size(extradataByte.length);
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("extradata file not available");
        }

        result = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, para);
        if(result < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to copy parameters to context! [" + result + "]");
        }

        codecContext.thread_count(0);

        result = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, new AVDictionary());
        if(result < 0)
        {
            releaseUnsafe();
            throw new Exception("Unable to open codec context![" + result + "]");
        }

        AVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        if(AVFrame == null)
        {
            releaseUnsafe();
            throw new Exception("Unable to alloc AVFrame!");
        }

        RGBAVFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        if(RGBAVFrame == null)
        {
            releaseUnsafe();
            throw new Exception("Unable to alloc AVFrame!");
        }
        initRGBAVFrame();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                timerTask();
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, (long) (1000/streamFramerateDouble));

        window.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The file extradata.byte has some bytes that I got from another video, because without them it doesn't work too.

**EDIT:**

```
package org.stratostream.streaming;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


import org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec.AVPacket;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec.AVPacketSideData;


public class PacketIO {


    public static final int SIDE_DATA_FIELD = 0;
    public static final int SIDE_ELEMENTS_FIELD = 4;
    public static final int SIDE_TYPE_FIELD = 8;
    public static final int DTS_FIELD = 12;
    public static final int PTS_FIELD = 20;
    public static final int FLAGS_FIELD = 28;
    public static final int DATA_OFFSET = 32;

    public static byte[] toByte(AVPacket packet) throws Exception
    {
        int dataSize = packet.size();
        ByteBuffer dataBuffer = packet.data().capacity(dataSize).asByteBuffer();
        byte dataBytes[] = new byte[dataSize];
        dataBuffer.get(dataBytes);

        AVPacketSideData sideData = packet.side_data();
        int sideSize = sideData.size();
        ByteBuffer sideBuffer = sideData.data().capacity(sideSize).asByteBuffer();
        byte sideBytes[] = new byte[sideSize];
        sideBuffer.get(sideBytes);

        int sideOffset = DATA_OFFSET + dataSize;
        int resultSize = sideOffset + sideSize;
        byte resultBytes[] = new byte[resultSize];
        System.arraycopy(dataBytes, 0, resultBytes, DATA_OFFSET, dataSize);
        System.arraycopy(sideBytes, 0, resultBytes, sideOffset, sideSize);
        resultBytes[SIDE_DATA_FIELD] = (byte) (sideOffset >>> 24);
        resultBytes[SIDE_DATA_FIELD+1] = (byte) (sideOffset >>> 16);
        resultBytes[SIDE_DATA_FIELD+2] = (byte) (sideOffset >>> 8);
        resultBytes[SIDE_DATA_FIELD+3] = (byte) (sideOffset >>> 0);

        int sideType = sideData.type();
        intToByte(resultBytes, SIDE_TYPE_FIELD, sideType);

        int sideElements = packet.side_data_elems();
        intToByte(resultBytes, SIDE_ELEMENTS_FIELD, sideElements);

        long dts = packet.dts();
        longToByte(resultBytes, DTS_FIELD, dts);

        long pts = packet.pts();
        longToByte(resultBytes, PTS_FIELD, pts);

        int flags = packet.flags();
        intToByte(resultBytes, FLAGS_FIELD, flags);

        return resultBytes;
    }

    public static AVPacket toPacket(byte bytes[]) throws Exception
    {
        AVPacket packet = avcodec.av_packet_alloc();

        int sideOffset = byteToInt(bytes, SIDE_DATA_FIELD);
        int sideElements = byteToInt(bytes, SIDE_ELEMENTS_FIELD);
        int sideType = byteToInt(bytes, SIDE_TYPE_FIELD);
        int dataSize = sideOffset - DATA_OFFSET;
        int sideSize = bytes.length - sideOffset;

        long pts = byteToLong(bytes, PTS_FIELD);
        long dts = byteToLong(bytes, DTS_FIELD);
        int flags = byteToInt(bytes, FLAGS_FIELD);

        packet.pts(pts);
        packet.dts(dts);
        packet.flags(flags);


        Pointer newDataPointer =  avutil.av_malloc(bytes.length);
        BytePointer dataPointer = new BytePointer(newDataPointer);
        byte dataBytes[] = new byte[dataSize];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, DATA_OFFSET, dataBytes, 0, dataSize);
        dataPointer.put(dataBytes);
        packet.data(dataPointer);
        packet.size(dataSize);

        Pointer newSidePointer = avutil.av_malloc(sideSize);
        BytePointer sidePointer = new BytePointer(newSidePointer);
        byte sideBytes[] = new byte[sideSize];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, sideOffset, sideBytes, 0, sideSize);
        sidePointer.put(sideBytes);
        AVPacketSideData sideData = new AVPacketSideData();
        sideData.data(sidePointer);
        sideData.type(sideType);
        sideData.size(sideSize);
        //packet.side_data(sideData);
        //packet.side_data_elems(sideElements);

        return packet;
    }

    private static void intToByte(byte[] bytes, int offset, int value)
    {
        bytes[offset] = (byte) (value >>> 24);
        bytes[offset+1] = (byte) (value >>> 16);
        bytes[offset+2] = (byte) (value >>> 8);
        bytes[offset+3] = (byte) (value >>> 0);
    }

    private static void longToByte(byte[] bytes, int offset, long value)
    {
        bytes[offset] = (byte) (value >>> 56);
        bytes[offset+1] = (byte) (value >>> 48);
        bytes[offset+2] = (byte) (value >>> 40);
        bytes[offset+3] = (byte) (value >>> 32);
        bytes[offset+4] = (byte) (value >>> 24);
        bytes[offset+5] = (byte) (value >>> 16);
        bytes[offset+6] = (byte) (value >>> 8);
        bytes[offset+7] = (byte) (value >>> 0);
    }

    private static int byteToInt(byte[] bytes, int offset)
    {
        return (bytes[offset]<<24)&0xff000000|(bytes[offset+1]<<16)&0x00ff0000|(bytes[offset+2]<<8)&0x0000ff00|(bytes[offset+3]<<0)&0x000000ff;
    }

    private static long byteToLong(byte[] bytes, int offset)
    {
        return (bytes[offset]<<56)&0xff00000000000000L|(bytes[offset+1]<<48)&0x00ff000000000000L|(bytes[offset+2]<<40)&0x0000ff0000000000L|(bytes[offset+3]<<32)&0x000000ff00000000L|(bytes[offset+4]<<24)&0x00000000ff000000L|(bytes[offset+5]<<16)&0x0000000000ff0000L|(bytes[offset+6]<<8)&0x000000000000ff00L|(bytes[offset+7]<<0)&0x00000000000000ffL;
    }

}
```

Now I have this class that works fine on the same programm, but when I send the bytes over the network I get a bad output and this error is printed to the console:

```
[h264 @ 00000242442acc40] Missing reference picture, default is 72646
[h264 @ 000002424089de00] Missing reference picture, default is 72646
[h264 @ 000002424089e3c0] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 000002424081a580] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 000002424081a580] Missing reference picture, default is 72652
[h264 @ 000002424082c400] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 000002424082c400] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000002424082c9c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 00000242442acc40] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 000002424089de00] mmco: unref short failure
```

I think its because I dont set the sidedata field but when I try to set it the encoder crashes with the second packet.

The output looks like this:
[Decoder Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEU2s.jpg)

Comment: what `This gives me this Error`? The sending size or the receiving side? What type is `videoPlayer`? How is `videoPlayer` serializing the metadata? What protocol is the receive expecting?

Comment: videoPlayer is my own class, that creates a JFrame and it sends the newPacket directly to the encoder with '`int result = avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet);`, `result` is -1094995529 and the error above is printed to the console. And currently I'm just trying to convert the packet to bytes and back without sending them over network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

AVFrame to bytes:

```
    int dataSize = packet.size();
    ByteBuffer dataBuffer = packet.data().capacity(dataSize).asByteBuffer();
    byte dataBytes[] = new byte[dataSize];
    dataBuffer.get(dataBytes);

    AVPacketSideData sideData = packet.side_data();
    int sideSize = sideData.size();
    ByteBuffer sideBuffer = sideData.data().capacity(sideSize).asByteBuffer();
    byte sideBytes[] = new byte[sideSize];
    sideBuffer.get(sideBytes);

    int sideType = sideData.type();
    int sideElements = packet.side_data_elems();
    long dts = packet.dts();
    long pts = packet.pts();
    int flags = packet.flags();
```

Bytes back to AVFrame:

```
    packet = avcodec.av_packet_alloc();
    packet.pts(pts);
    packet.dts(dts);
    packet.flags(flags);

    Pointer newDataPointer =  avutil.av_malloc(dataSize);
    BytePointer dataPointer = new BytePointer(newDataPointer);
    dataPointer.put(dataBytes);
    packet.data(dataPointer);
    packet.size(dataSize);

    Pointer newSidePointer = avutil.av_malloc(sideSize);
    BytePointer sidePointer = new BytePointer(newSidePointer);
    sidePointer.put(sideBytes);

    BytePointer sideDataPointer = avcodec.av_packet_new_side_data(packet, sideType, sideSize);
    AVPacketSideData sideData = new AVPacketSideData(sideDataPointer);
    sideData.data(sidePointer);
    sideData.type(sideType);
    sideData.size(sideSize);
    packet.side_data(sideData);
    packet.side_data_elems(sideElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to to `AVPacket.data()` returns a `BytePointer` which is a wrapper for the native C++ pointer. There is no capacity information associated with a pointer which means you need to set the capacity manually. You probably need something like:

```
int packetSize = packet.size();
ByteBuffer dataBuffer = packet.data().capacity(packetSize).asByteBuffer();
```

Comment: Now it works sometimes. The decoder returns almost every second packet `-1094995529` and i prints this error to the console: ```Error splitting the input into NAL units.
No start code is found.
Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Missing reference picture, default is 65580
reference picture missing during reorder
mmco: unref short failure
 Reference 3 >= 2
 error while decoding MB 107 13, bytestream 35
concealing 6542 DC, 6542 AC, 6542 MV errors in B frame
reference picture missing during reorder
 mmco: unref short failure```

Comment: And I found out, that I get the same result when I only set the `data()` and `size()` field of the new packet. So I don't need to set the dts, pts ...